# How do I plot a non-stacked and non-side-by-side horizontal bar chart with matplotlib/pandas?

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

Basically, I want all bars overlapping, but I don't want them to stack nor to be side-by-side. I want them overlapping, but if I try to do overlapping bars with pyplot, it doesn't automatically organize it so that the smaller bars are up front and the bigger ones are in the back. Some bars get completely hidden. I don't want to use the alpha attribute because there are too many colors and it's easy to become confusing when they merge. Here is my code:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv("flow_actions.csv", index_col="weekday")

def pandas_chart(df, **kwargs):
    df.plot.barh(**kwargs)
    plt.grid(axis="x")
    plt.legend()
    plt.show()

def pyplot_chart(df, **kwargs):
    for col in df:
        plt.barh(y=df.index.values, 
                 width=df[col].values,
                 label=col,
                 height=0.8)
    plt.legend()
    plt.grid(axis="x")
    plt.show()
```

This is the dataset I'm working with:

```
+---------+--------------+--------------+----------+---------+--------+
| weekday | E-mail(auto) | E-mail(semi) | LinkedIn | Ligação | Social |
+---------+--------------+--------------+----------+---------+--------+
| Mon     | 0.15         | 0.02         | 0.04     | 0.08    | 0      |
| Tue     | 0.1          | 0.03         | 0.03     | 0.05    | 0.01   |
| Wed     | 0.12         | 0.02         | 0.05     | 0.07    | 0.02   |
| Thu     | 0.13         | 0.02         | 0.04     | 0.06    | 0.01   |
| Fri     | 0.15         | 0.04         | 0.04     | 0.05    | 0.02   |
| Sat     | 0.15         | 0.01         | 0.03     | 0.08    | 0      |
| Sun     | 0.16         | 0.01         | 0.02     | 0.06    | 0.01   |
+---------+--------------+--------------+----------+---------+--------+
```

Here are some (undesired) outputs:

```
>>> pandas_chart(df)
```

output:

[image]

```
>>> pandas_chart(df, stacked=True)
```

output:

[image]

```
>>> pyplot_chart(df)
```

output:

[image]

The thing is, I want something between images #3 and #2, but I don't want the values stacked like in #2 nor I want them hidden by other bars like in 3. Is such thing possible, or do I have to stick with #1 (which looks uglier the more categories you have)?

Comment: Post your dataframe as text, not as an image.

Comment: Also, I think #2 is going to be the cleanest and easiest to understand overall.

Comment: I'm sorry about the image dataframe, I was struggling with having it formatted properly.
I understand that some of these are cleaner and better looking, but I was just wondering if there was some code already done for my request. It would be nice to have the option to compare these to the one I want.

Comment: You may have to use an image editor to show desired result as it is not clear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I understand that you want something like #3. This might lead to problems, if some values are similar within the same row. But otherwise, you can create your own sorting of the columns to prevent that larger values cover smaller ones.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd
from matplotlib import cm
from itertools import cycle

df = pd.read_csv("test.csv", index_col = "weekday")

def pyplot_chart(df):

    #create dictionary for colors by cycling through a predefined colour list
    color_cycle = cycle([ 'k', 'b', 'r', 'y', 'c', 'm', 'g'])
    col_dic = {col: next(color_cycle) for col in df}
    #alternatively, extract colours along a defined colormap
    #see color maps reference https://matplotlib.org/examples/color/colormaps_reference.html
    #col_dic = {col: cm.tab20c(1 - i / len(df.columns)) for i, col in enumerate(df)}

    #cycle through each row of the dataframe
    for yvalue, row in df.iterrows():
        #sort the values within the row, plot largest values first
        for index, value in row.sort_values(ascending = False).iteritems():
            plt.barh(y=yvalue,
                     width=value,
                     color=col_dic[index],
                     height=0.8)

    #plot invisible columns for labels
    for col in df.columns:
        plt.barh(y=df.index,
                 width=0,
                 color=col_dic[col],
                 label = col,
                 height=0)

    plt.legend()
    plt.grid(axis="x")
    plt.show()

pyplot_chart(df)
```

Output:
[image]

As you can see, on Tuesday, where two values are 0.3, you can't distinguish, whether LinkedIn exists or not. You could try to overcome this problem by modifying the `width` parameter as well, i.e., smaller values have also a smaller width to show similar values behind them.